# r timeline in swimlanes by state

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my test dataset

```
State     MinWage      From    To     DataFrom    DataTo
AK        No           1994    2017   
AL        No           1994    2017   2005        2019
AR        No           1994    2017   2006        2018
AZ        No           1994    2017   2005        2019
CA        Yes          2015    2017   1992        2019
CO        Yes          1999    2017   
CT        Yes          2011    2017   2003        2019
DC        Yes          2000    2017   2003        2017
```

I am trying to create a timeline line like this where each state is in a swimlane

[image]

The broken lines depict `DataFrom - DataTo`

The solid lines depict `From - To`

Red lines are those with MinWage=No

Blue lines are those with MinWage=Yes

Any suggestions on how to plot this figure is much appreciated.

Comment: How bout [swimplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/swimplot/vignettes/Introduction.to.swimplot.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group = State, color = MinWage, y = State, yend = State)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = From, xend = pmin(To, DataFrom, na.rm = T))) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = pmax(From, DataFrom), xend = pmin(DataTo, To)), linetype = 2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = pmax(From, DataTo), xend = To), color = "blue") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = From, label = From), color = "darkgrey", vjust = 1.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = To, label = To), color = "darkgrey", vjust = 1.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = DataFrom, label = DataFrom), color = "darkgrey", vjust = 1.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = DataTo, label = DataTo), color = "darkgrey", vjust = 1.5) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2020, 5), limits = c(1990, 2020)) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) + 
  labs(x = NULL) + 
  guides(color = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You may try(do not know condition of color)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(DataFrom = ifelse(is.na(DataFrom), From, DataFrom),
         DataTo = ifelse(is.na(DataTo), From, DataTo)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(group = State)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = DataFrom, xend = DataTo, y = State, yend = State), linetype = 2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = From, xend = DataFrom, y = State, yend = State)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = DataTo, xend = To, y = State, yend = State))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question regarding colors which are based on MinWage value, if MinWage=Yes then line color Red else Blue

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai Is there specific reason that for `AZ, AR, AL`, end of the line's color is different?

Comment: yes because `MinWage == No` for `State = AK, AZ, AR, AL`

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai Oh, I mean that end of those are blue.